# How can I have two instances of rhythmbox running or how to program rhythmbox to start playing at previous position in a mp3 file?

Tags: ubuntu, mp3, media, gnome

I like to alternate between listening to internet radio and other things e.g. a podcast, but don't like to lose my place in the podcast file. And oddly, sometimes in the process of fast forwarding in an audio file, rhythmbox just quits.

Or instead of having two instances of rhythmbox, would I be able to write a program so that it can automatically return to the previous position in the mp3 file I was listening to (i.e. when I go back to the podcast section).

Edit: I would also like to be able to open rhythmbox and automatically or easily return to a position in an audio file that I was listening to before closing it.

Comment: Quick-n-dirty: Use one music program for listening to internet radio or podcasts, and another for listening to your MP3s.

Comment: Do you know of a music program where it is easier to navigate files as I have described in my question?

Comment: Or where you think I could easily write a script to do what I want it to do as described?

Answer (score 0):

Banshee (http://banshee-project.org/) lets you bookmark specific positions in a track and open them later. It's also an excellent media player, and I prefer it to Rhythmbox.

Comment: FYI On Ubuntu 9.10 they still haven't fixed Last.fm support.

Comment: That is, in the version in the repos, Last.fm playback is completely broken.

Comment: The OP did not mention last.fm.